# BC547 & LDR with multiple LED's

Tags: ldr

I'm new to electronics and I want to make a LDR controlled night light with multiple led's. I use a 3V battery pack, which I can power the LED's with, without the LDR setup it works just fine.

I have the following components:

3x LED's 20ma 3v
4.5V battery pack
LDR1 GL5537-1   @10 lux20-30kΩ Darkness resistance~3MΩ
BC547
Resistors

My questions now is how much Resistance should I use for the fixed resistor R2 so that LDR1 still has the ON/OFF feature?

[image]

Comment: You might want to explain how did you connect the multiple LEDs to make sure we understand what you are trying to do and why it does not work. Best guess: you tried them in parallel?

Comment: Please use the site search feature to find out how to interconnect several LEDs.

Comment: @pythor, You may find something [like this](https://www.instructables.com/Joule-Thief-LED-Night-Light/) closer to what you would like to have. I've not reviewed the circuit. I only just found it from a google search. But the basic idea is that you want a boost circuit to boost the voltage of your battery so that you can string your LEDs in series (all sharing the same current setting.) But you also want it to be a night light using an LDR. So it's not the usual joule thief thingy. Anyway, that might be an option for you to consider.

Comment: I got the lights to work using Glen's setup below, however they're very dim. What resistor do I have to use at R4 to have em bright enough?

 I tweaked the setup to include a 4.5V battery pack instead of a 3V battery. How can I select the best resistor for R4 to include the right ON/OFF transition and brightness?

I'm using the LDR1 **GL5537-1** @10 lux20-30kΩ  Darkness resistance~3MΩ

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make multiple LED's work? Do I have to add more resistors?

Yes, a resistor for each LED, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLAcdz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For white LEDs, 3V battery is almost too small, because a white LED consumes most of that. You may find that a weak battery gives little/no light. A green LED might be OK, and RED LED should be fine with 3V battery.

When you add LEDs like this, you're asking Q1 to work harder. To get the same ON/OFF transition point, you may have to use a smaller value resistor at R4 (47k).
Be sure that **LDR1** cannot see any of the LEDs.

---

Edit...
Re-calculating darkness threshold level.
Am unsure of LDR resistance at threshold, so am calculating base current with one LED from OP's schematic with 3V supply, and base dropping resistor of 50k...

Transistor base threshold would be around 0.6V, so that 50k dropping resistor would require the LDR to have roughly 12k resistance. At this point, the transistor is *barely* turning on, supplying a fraction of a milliamp to the LED with a 3V supply.
As darkness falls, LDR resistance climbs higher, resulting in more base current, which causes the transistor to enter saturation region, and LED current rises...the resistor in series with the LED limits current (and brightness of LED) in full darkness.
A well-saturated transistor might have 0.1V drop from collector to emitter, so there's now 2.9V left for LED and its associated series resistor.
A red LED might drop 1.7V, leaving 1.2V across the resistor - a 100 ohm resistor would allow 12mA in full darkness.

Since most LEDs will easily handle 20mA, you could drop the series resistor from 100 ohms to 47 ohms, which would double the LED brightness. This with a 3V supply. 2X brightness isn't much brighter to the eye.

If you wish to use three LEDs, 10mA each, then each LED would have a series resistor of 100 ohms (as in the left schematic). This with a 3V supply.
Changing to a 4.5V supply, 10mA would flow in each LED if series resistance was about 270 ohms.
With 4.5V supply, threshold transistor turn-on is achieved with a 82k dropping resistor to LDR2 (and base of transistor). This resistor might be made slightly smaller (75k, or possibly 68k) because more base current is flowing.

If LEDs are **white**, the 4.5V three-cell supply is recommended, but R5, R6, R7 should be dropped to about 100 ohms each. These white LEDs drop about 3.3V whereas RED LEDs drop about 1.7V. The 3V supply is too small to properly excite white LEDs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Glen. How much smaller do you think the resistor should be at R4?  I tweaked the setup to include a 4.5V battery pack instead of a 3V battery. How can I select the best resistor for R4 to include the ON/OFF transition?

I'm using the GL5537-1  @10 lux20-30kΩ  Darkness resistance~3MΩ